# Did virtual devices have temporary memory?

Tags: android, memory, android-emulator, android-external-storage

While I was using a virtual device to test my application I noticed that sometimes, after the device has been turned off for a while (for example: I used the device to test my app today; turned off the computer; and after 2 days I used the device again to test an update), when I ran the application again the data had been reset. But that doesn't happen (apparently) when I'm using a real device, like my phone or my friend's tablet.

My question is: this loss of memory is normal to happen with virtual devices or is there a problem with my app? I'm kind of worried with it, because if an user loses his data is a serious problem.

I store the data here, in external storage:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
      new FileOutputStream(
         Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyApplication/data.dat"));
oos.writeObject(dataset);
oos.close();
```

** as you may understand I already checked all my code to try to find something, and I can't put the whole code here, that's not the point.

Answer (score 0):

Android Emulator or Virtual Device never lose data on system shutdown....(As much as i have seen till now).....Try creating a new virtual device and try again. Hope it works.....while setting up the device make sure you allocate enough space for External storage and Internal Storage.

Comment: The problem is the device don't always loses the data. Is just in some cases, after X installs and etc..

Answer (score 0):

Virtual device save data before shutdown, but there is option in eclipse ( if you are developing with eclipse ) where you can set reset on every launch